# Permission denied creating package in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a cms package that I will be using. The problem that I'm having is that after I published my package I can't get it to work. I'm getting this error

> ErrorException in CmsServiceProvider.php line 35: include(C:\wamp\www\laravel_package\packages\testing\cms\src\Modules): failed to open stream: Permission denied

This is my CmsServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace Testing\Cms;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CmsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/Modules' => base_path('app/Modules'),
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

        include __DIR__.'/Modules';
    }
}
```

Line 35 is

```
include __DIR__.'/Modules';
```

If there is anything else that I need to give in order to help me with my problem please let me know. I wasn't sure on all the info I needed to give.

Comment: did u fixed it, if u did please share it whit me

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the folder you are trying to open doesn't have the correct permissions. Try changing the permission for the `Modules` folder and all files within the folder to allow read / write.

Comment: I've tried that but I'm still getting the error and also no matter how many times I try it still keeps selecting read only in the properties folder

Comment: They try setting permissions at a higher level, e.g. `C:\wamp\www\laravel_package\packages\testing\cms`

Comment: I've gone up all the way to the www folder and I'm still not able to uncheck the read only box

Comment: You may need to do it as administrator.

Comment: I am the administrator and my admin settings is all checked